# Should I delete my question if it is marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I just asked a question and pretty quickly it got marked as a duplicate ([for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765362/remove-array-of-characters-from-string)). I'm totally fine with that since it means other users knew of a related question I wasn't able to find before asking a new question.

The question is, should I go ahead and delete my question now or should I leave it out there for future users? What is the policy?

Comment: You could delete it but if you do it too often then you will be suspended from posting.

Comment: I believe you're recommended to keep it around, since it's another path by which the target could be found.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Please don't delete your duplicate question.

Duplicates act as *sign posts*, lighting the way to the canonical question. Your question used different keywords, different language to ask about the same concept, and now those keywords can be used to find the original.

If you deleted your post you'd remove the sign-post, leaving a future searcher with the same keywords stranded, doomed to ask the duplicate again.

Comment: @iCodez such duplicates *need to be merged* into the canonical answer, so that answers are all consolidated into one place, not spread across multiple posts.

Comment: People downvote duplicate posts, though. I thought the point of down-voting was that it showed the question shouldn't have been asked and should be deleted.

Comment: Your dupe *could* be downvoted because it is obvious; if a quick search with the same keywords would have found the original or another dupe then *another* duplicate doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I disagree with this. If your question is a duplicate with a different wording then maybe the wording of the original should be changed so it is easier to find. If the same question can be phrased in entirely different ways then perhaps the question is too broad to begin with.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: so every time someone with low reputation comes up with a different way to explain an abstract concept that happens to be a dupe, you'll edit the original question to include that alternative? The original question asker won't have the right to, nor the inclination, and this isn't mere synonyms we are talking about here.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: but at the same time, someone *already did that work*, by asking the dupe. Why not re-use that work then?

Comment: What if I think the duplicate question does not serve any purpose and it costs me some negative points?

Comment: @Rajaraman you are not required to keep it; but if you do there may be benefits to the site and future visitors.

Comment: Yes, that's why I kept it and it makes sense to keep it so that it act as signpost as you have suggested but how to avoid negative points in that case?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, what do I do if some answer in another question which isn't asking the same thing answers my question and somebody marked it as a duplicate of it, I constantly keep getting downvotes just because of that

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: start by not assuming you know why someone downvoted. If you feel there are already enough duplicate posts that use the same wording, it's fine to delete your post. Just don't delete it *solely* because it is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for _"Just don't delete it solely because it is a duplicate"_, that makes a lot of sense.