# SO Policy on asking to be marked as accepted

Tags: discussion, comments, accepted-answer

**What is the Stack Overflow policy on asking original posters to mark answers as accepted, if they've already verbally suggested via comment that your solution worked for them?**

This has come up a few times over my recent sprint of question-answering on Stack Overflow, but I surprisingly haven't been able to find a meta question about it.

It seems a pretty common case for me that a new user will ask a question, I'll give an answer, then they'll comment on it thanking me and saying "looks good." I generally give a bit of time then, both for them to figure out my answer and the site and even have other users who might have better suggestions answer as well, but after a while passes, I want to nudge them along and suggest they accept my answer.

As we all know, that has some distinct advantages for everyone:

- It's nice to have the question off the unanswered list
- It'll make people in the future be better able to find the answer
- To be frank, it's nice to get the rep points after I've worked at least marginally hard to give a full, thought-out answer.

So is there a culturally appropriate way to nudge new users along to accepting an answer? Or even older users who've just forgotten? In the past, I've replied to "thanks!" comments saying, for instance, "glad I could help, and by the way when you get a moment it would be great if you could mark this as an accepted answer. That will help users in the future with similar situations find help, and it will take this question off of the unanswered queue." But I sometimes feel like that's--I don't know--un-SO-like? I don't see other people doing it very often, and it just seems dirty to straight-up ask someone for something that will give me rep points, even if that's not the entirety of my reasoning behind it.

I know on other forum sites like MSDN, it's in many top contributors' signatures to include "if this answer helped you please be sure to mark it as an answer," but is that frowned upon here? Or is the reason I don't see it more just that people *tend* to know and remember to accept answers?

As I said, it has an overall positive influence on the community to have more accepted answers, so it's not like it's a strictly selfish desire of mine. Even the accepter gets rep points (albeit two), so it's definitely indicated that we want accepted answers to be accepted.

But even on the selfish end of things, on some questions, like [C# read csv, calculate something, export another csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25053175/c-sharp-read-csv-calculate-something-export-another-csv?noredirect=1#comment38971666_25053175) for example, I put in a fair bit of effort to write out that answer to conform to the OP's situation and explain what I was doing, and I would appreciate at least having the answer be accepted if it did, in fact, answer the question. This particular one is the classic situation where this was a first post by a new user, and he commented (albeit on his actual question), saying that my code did what he wanted. It looks like he's still working with my code so he might still accept it, but the principle remains.

Furthermore, if these comments *are*, in fact, acceptable, what sort of timeframe should be given before making them? As I said, I like to wait a bit before I urge them along, because I want them to have an opportunity to understand my code and make sure it actually does what they're looking for, and I want other people to have a chance to answer as well. But at the same time, particularly for relatively unengaged users, they might log in only to see the answer, comment "thanks," then be gone in minutes, never to return.

I want to be clear, of course, that I'm not making any suggestion here that we push to be accepted if we aren't the best answer. Clearly that's inappropriate for a myriad of reasons. But I'm just talking about those cases where we *are* the best answer, and the original poster has already told us that we answered their question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Alas, your searching capabilities exceed my own. Hate it when that happens. Thanks! I was half on my way to deleting this post when I actually had a successful search tell me I shouldn't. So for the record, I'm agreeing with the close vote but leaving this open on the grounds of [this SO meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/1270504) (which, yes, happens to be yours).

Comment: I personally encourage new users to accept good answers, both mine and other people's. I can't force them, nor would I want to, but they should know that there's a way they can "formally" thank the user for a good answer.