# Delete question or close own post as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently asked a question on SO, and after a couple days I answered it, but around the same time I determined that it was effectively a duplicate of an older existing post. As such, I thought it would be appropriate to delete my post and simply answer the existing question. However, when I deleted it I was warned that since my question had an answer, deleting it wasn't recommended and deleting answered questions could lead to a question ban. Is that still applicable in a case of a self-answer? I ended up deleting the answer and then the question - is that the best way to resolve the solution, or should I have left the question undeleted and worked to close it as a duplicate?

This question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate), because that question regards whether or not you should delete a question **after** it has been marked as a duplicate. In this case, I'm asking about the specifics of how I should handle the realization that my own question is a duplicate, after I have self-answered but before it has been officially marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Unless your question had something unique in it that could help future visitors, I''d say you were right to delete your question.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think my question added anything significant - I just want to make sure that I'm not doing something that the system is going to mistakenly count towards a question ban.

Comment: As long as your user account isn't close to a question-ban, you're probably completely in the clear if you removed only that one question.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is, as so often, **it depends**.

*Some* duplication is useful and neccessary to set up all the sign-posts we want.
For a question to qualify, it should be of good quality, and describe the problem differently than other duplicates or the master.

Obviously, if it's a frequent duplicate, it's quite unlikely to **describe the problem in a sufficiently different way** to enhance searchability.

Also, if it's a duplicate, it should not collect any answers, the additional answer, if it really adds to those already there, should be put on the master.
Kudos for figuring out that's the appropriate place for yours.
Even higher honor if you also carefully weighed the appropriateness of adding an additional answer.

As an aside, if the question is not answered nor downvoted, deleting it won't be all that significant, despite the warning.
And if it is answered, you probably cannot remove it anyway, so the question is academic.
As a last point, if it is downvoted, it might be impossible to salvage it anyway, so a fast delete is good to limit the damage. Just keep it in mind that a longer search might have been fruitful *next time*.

Comment: This is good advice, but I guess I'm also looking for more of a technical answer - whether the system considers it a "bad thing" if I delete a self answer and then delete the question. But I guess the answer I'm getting is "just don't worry about it".