# What to do about question that turns out to be a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There is [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284274/delete-question-or-close-own-post-as-duplicate) on meta on a rather similar topic.

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852615/calling-cgi-script-from-other-cgi-script) on what I found to be a strange behavior in a perl script. I had found, and mentioned, a related post in my question which however did not cover my case.

Now that the question is answered, I seem to be getting lots of suggestions for related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002664/why-does-my-system-call-to-another-cgi-script-work-on-the-command-line-but-not-w?rq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866826/strange-behavior-when-passing-parameters-to-a-perl-cgi-script-from-another-perl?rq=1) which I missed when initially submitting the question.

My question was answered and even upvoted once, but now I feel that it should actually be closed as duplicate, but in the meta link it says that 'if it is answered, you probably cannot remove it'.

Should I flag my question as duplicate? Ask for deletion? Something else entirely?

Any advise on what I should be doing in this case would be appreciated.

Comment: If your question is indeed a duplicate, feel free to close it as such. Duplicates _are not_ bad things! Actually, duplicates that are worded differently can help people find their answer easier even if they don't word the question the same way as the original post.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kendra points out in [their comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297542/what-to-do-about-question-that-turns-out-to-be-a-duplicate#comment209971_297542) and as the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) jonrsharpe found, duplicates can be of great benefit. If you didn't find the original question when you were searching, there's a good chance others won't too. So having the problem restated in a different way will help others in the future.

So, you don't need to delete but you can flag for closing as a duplicate and if you get the notification that the questions is being closed, answer "yes" to the question and it'll be closed straight away.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if 250 rep is enough for asker to do this unilaterally. At 3K, [it is certainly so](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/198549/revisions "example") - vote to close, refresh to see the prompt (triggered by your own vote), answer yes

Comment: @gnat Even without 250 rep, all they have to do is flag, refresh, then hit close. A flag will trigger the prompt as well.

Comment: @Kendra that makes it 50 rep instead of 250, right? if memory serves, that's rep requirement to dupe-flag, as it makes a comment. I think I like that new self-dupe-close system more and more

Comment: I would think so, but since you can comment on your own question, it begs the question of if you can automatically dupe-flag your own question... But in theory, yes, it's 50 rep min.