# Time to [wrap] it up, [wrap] is no longer on the menu

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) tag is not useful, and isn't specific enough so it means different things in different contexts. The current wiki for [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) is

> Cover, enclose, fit around something (object, tag ...)

That is the definition of the word "wrap" and has nothing (specifically) to do with any particular programming language. Therefore, since the tag description is not useful, the tag gets misused.

For example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098418/wrapped-or-not-wrapped-json) is referring to "wrapped JSON" whereas other posts seem to be referring to [wrapper functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function) or [text wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821632/netbeans-java-jtable-text-wrap-issue) or [nested `div`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32034225/wrap-div-around-posts-in-same-category).

My two cents is to burninate the tag, or at least decide which of the many contexts it applies to and fix the wiki to make it clear.

Comment: I think the first 3 of these 4 meanings are valuable (subject to bikeshedding): [tag:text-wrapping], [tag:html-wrapping], [tag:function-wrapper], [tag:data-wrapper]

Comment: @o11c: well, I can see an expert in text-wrapping (it's surprisingly tricky), but who would be an expert in function or data wrapping?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: +56/-2 No answers.

Comment: I added a note to the tag wiki (but it's under review)

Comment: It's not just that it gets misused - is there any "correct" usage of this?

Comment: Seems quite clear, will move forward with this in an hour or so.

Comment: @BhargavRao Off-topic a little: you wanted to be moderator to clean up the pending burnination requests, didn't you? :)

Comment: @Camilo, not just burn requests, but all tag related requests ... there's like 2.5k+ of them, and we've gone through 50%... the goal is to get to 80% by the end of the next decade ... need your help too!

Comment: @BhargavRao 80% by the end of 2030?

Comment: @Camilo Yep. Might sound a bit too far off, but it's atleast a date, as opposed to 6~8 weeks ;p

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +113/-4 A1 (Saying Yes) +37/-1. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: and that's a [wrap]

Comment: @BhargavRao Shouldn't time be better spent convincing the company that better tools are needed? 11 years to finish less than 1000 requests sounds like too much wasted time

Comment: @Camilo, The issue is that the community has to decide these. They have to go through the posts, and see if any of them even need to be retagged or closed, or deleted or something else... For now, if the tag has more than 1000 questions, we can simply rope in a CM to just delete the tag after cleaning up the non-positive scored questions. Something which would be really great is, 1. More top users of a tag looking at these requests as they come in and either vote/comment on them. 2. More general users participating in the burns to review, rather than the same subset  who've been doing it.

Comment: For the syn-requests, merge-requests, etc, as a moderator, I can handle them in seconds... So they're not a problem at all.. The problem is the retag-requests, burn-requests and tag-disambiguation requests.

Comment: @BhargavRao I understand. I don't accept that there aren't better solutions though. An easy tool would be a special burnination view. A more elaborate one would be to use bots. That's without thinking what comes off the top of my mind, I'm sure there could be far better solutions if the time was taken to analyze this issue.

Comment: @Camilo Yep, a view would be great, and the community has done a few bots, like this one https://stackapps.com/questions/7027, to manage these. Do drop any idea that you get in this room. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/165597/trogdor, whenever you have the time to think about it. We need more and more users to share their ideas, so that we can come up with an easier way for these. Feel free to ping me there.

Comment: `Wrapping`, as in `texture-wrapping` is a used in 3D graphics. It means that a picture (texture) literally encloses the 3D object like a skin, which has to be correctly mapped. So, (at least `wrapping`) may still be useful, to some extent. Or let's rename it `UV-Unwrapping` or `texture-wrapping` (maybe more generic)

Comment: @Fantômas, there is a retagging/cleanup effort underway for the [wrapping] tag, and has been decided to be merged with [text-wrapping]. The idea is to retag all the questions not related to [text-wrapping], including the texture-wrapping questions that you mention, before the merge. Feel free to join in and contribute to the effort.

Answer (score 37):

Yeah, let's burn it. The tag is ***too broad*** unless we split it up. It means too many things at the same time as mentioned in the comment area.

> 1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

No, it actually does not if it is tagged *only* with [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap). The question will be most likely closed as too broad and will Roomba, so it is clearly ambiguous.

> 2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Most of the questions tagged [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) are on-topic just because as far as I have seen they add [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) because their post contains the word 'wrap', however, tags should help define the *topic* of the question and should ***not*** be used if the question just contains what is mentioned in the tag.

> 3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, nope. Why would one want to know if the question is about [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap)ping something? Would it help anyone? There are more specific and helpful tags - more can be found from experts of the topic (i.e. experts of Python can find better tags to replace [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) with more helpful tags, etc.)

> 4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, as mentioned in 1. Depends heavily on the language and additionally, language-specific tags can be created to replace it.

So, I believe we should burninate this tag. It is too broad and meets all the burnination criteria.

Comment: Please add some retag-replace-with targets to your answer. At least some recommendations for some of the answers can be made.

Comment: @Joshua, I personally don't see the need for any replacement tags. Looking at the first page of Q's none would be unclear if it lacked the [tag:wrap] tag imho. If you see the need for replacements please do please suggest them.

Comment: See o11c's comment on the question.

Comment: What about this question, it seems to be a correct use of [wrap] : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531613/how-to-animate-a-growing-shrinking-wrap-widget

Comment: @VFDan that asks the question "do we need a tag for each function/method?" To which the most sensible answer is "No, we already have a tag for the language/framework/library that function/method belongs to"

Answer (score 8):

[wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use the [word-wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-wrap) tag for questions related to wrapping text on the next line.
- Use the [wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrapper) tag for questions related to the OOP concept of wrappers.
- Use the [wrapall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrapall) tag for questions related to the jQuery method which wraps an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements
- Use the [textwrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/textwrapping) tag for questions related to the method for fitting text into an area by moving any text that overflows its boundaries onto a new line.

## Progress:

The [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=wrap),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwrap%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwrap%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwrap%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwrap%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191869)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=302836)

[image: burnination progress chart]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Large Tag Guidance

Remember that [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) has more than 1200 questions. Therefore do not go through all of them! Retag the ones which are worth saving (usually the top voted posts) and vote to close the unsalvageable questions (usually the very low scored).

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wrap) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: Though there's really a good argument for burninating [tag:word-wrap] and [tag:wrapall], too...

Comment: Don't see a good argument for word-wrap, @TylerH... It is a valid programming concept, and is on-topic. It isn't ambiguous. The wrapall one might have one, but haven't looked into it.

Comment: @BharghavRao I was thinking of the CSS property but I suppose the function exists in other languages now that I think about it. Purely an ancillary tag, though, regardless.

Comment: Is there a tag for wrapping stuff with HTML tags? Because I've seen a lot of questions about that, but I haven't found any tag for that.

Comment: What about duplicates? [Duplicates shouldn't be deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/4284627), so should I remove the tag and vote to close as a duplicate?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Just close as dupe I think.  Handling that is a big part of why Bhargav Rao goes through and manually deletes questions at the end of the burn; that way he can edit the tag out to salvage anything worth keeping as dupe placeholder/etc.

Comment: @DanNeely In the second last paragraph (the one about downvoting to trigger roomba) it says that the questions will be mass-deleted. Doesn't that mean that they will be deleted automatically without anyone looking at them?

Comment: @DonaldDuck I'm commenting based on observed behavior.  The last tag burned [Player] had ~500 questions closed, and Bhargav Rao manually reviewed/deleted them.  This tag is much cleaner and seems likely to end with less than half as many questions being closed.  So I expect it will also get a manual review/delete, and that the SE employee mass delete hammer is reserved for a larger size of burn, and that the primary focus is on not down voting to trigger the roomba.  I can't find the post now, but there was a big stink about doing so on meta a few years ago.

Comment: @DonaldDuck mass-deleted == mass deleted manually by a moderator or a CM. Whenever the number of posts are within reach, I will delete them. If it is out of reach, a CM will check the posts once and delete them.

Comment: As for duplicates, I delete them if 1. The question has very low number of views compared to the dupe 2. If the answers posted are already present on the target. 3. If the duplicate hasn't been contested in the comments.