# Deleting questions marked duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33501298/2069064) yesterday. Another user (don't remember who) left a comment for a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17282151/2069064). Since they are clearly highly related, I dupe-hammered the former question. The OP for the duped question agreed with this, and deleted his question.

But it's not a bad question, and somebody else might come along who specifically needs iterators to multimap's stored in a hashtable too? I think it should stay open, so I flagged the question and got told:

> helpful - The asker decided to delete this themselves, and I'll defer to them.

Why defer? Don't we want to keep such questions open as signposts?

Comment: "Don't we want to keep such questions open as signposts?" No if all possible keywords are already in the target questions.

Comment: How did you make a case for undeletion in the flag you raised?

Comment: @Louis "This is a totally reasonable question that can be used as a signpost for future searches. Please undelete this question"

Comment: See also: [Should I delete my question if it is marked as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265736/1591669)

Comment: What about this question makes you think that users would find it in a search and not find the duplicate target?  As has been said, while it *possible* for *some* duplicates to make good signposts, the vast majority of duplicates do *not* make good signposts.