# Close question as dupe, and edit in answer in target to better handle the alleged duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, behavior

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811236/mutate-variable-in-fn-closure) earlier today. It was first singlehandedly marked as duplicate, and then after few minutes there was [an edit to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38677845/revisions) in the target of the duplicate.

I feel this is wrong for 2 reasons:

1. Finding information regarding the original question is now very difficult, since the answer is in the very bottom of unrelated question;
2. Marking a question as duplicate when it's not BEFORE even adding answer to some other question makes me off-put and not willing to ask anything else.

Can someone enlighten me how this is an ethical thing to do?

Comment: You were unlucky, your question was seen by the resident expert in the [rust] community.  Not just a bit expert either, Shepmaster is 3.14 times as good as everybody else that contributes to [rust].  Surely you can find bigger fools at a forum site to accommodate you.

Comment: I love how your sarcastic "nice" went completely over Shepmaster's head. Perfect.

Answer (score 8):

1. The questions aren't unrelated.  The questions are exact duplicates.  The solution to your problem is *the entirety* of the answer, not just some section of it.  People with that *one* problem should be reading the answer, and when they do, they'll have the solution to their problem.
2. It was a duplicate *before* any edits were made.  Your question is asking the exact same thing as the marked duplicate.  You posted a comment in which you stated that the existing solution didn't work for you, for reasons not even mentioned in the question.  This prompted the author of the answer to realize that their answer *to that one question, asked by both of you*, was incomplete and was missing some important information in order to be a good answer to that one question.  So they edited their question in response to your comment pointing out how the answer could be improved, to address that problem.

   Had they not performed the edit that they did in response to your comment (assuming you had edited that additional information on your problem into the question) it would have been grounds for reopening the question, as you'd have identified how the answer to the duplicate question failed to work for you, but since the edit has taken place, the duplicate no longer fails to answer your question, so that's not necessary.

Comment: It was not a duplicate from the very beginning, I explicitly stated that I am using a library, hence it is not in my control of what types of parameters library accepts. You did not even bother to read the question after the title, yet bothered to write this answer.

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, I did read the question.  I still feel that the questions are duplicates.  You're simply expecting people to be making assumptions about things not stated in your question.  Had you included, in your question, why the solution presented in that answer (before it was edited) didn't work for you, it wouldn't have been a duplicate (until the edit, then it would have become a duplicate).

Comment: how was I supposed to find an answer to my question before asking in the first place? I simply could not, hence the question. Moreover, it is an assumption that I CAN modify library interface, not the other way around, which was expected from me first.

Comment: @Mikhail I never said you *were* expected to find it before asking.  You were given the answer to your question in response to it being asked.  Whether or not it's a resource you could have been expected to find before asking is something I haven't commented on.

Comment: In case you didn't know question marked as duplicate by definition means that it already was answered elsewhere which means I should have found it on my own. Was it the case? No, I even bothered to explain why in the comments (even though it is the answerer who did not even bother to read question). Was it unlabeled and answered instead properly as it deserved? No, instead an answer elsewhere was updated so that now no one can find an answer to the original question. And don't say that my question was unclear - I explained why it was not the case (part of my comment you chose to ignore)

Comment: @Mikhail That the question is answered elsewhere doesn't always mean that other answer could reasonably have been found by the person asking the second question.  Often it does, but not always.  Some things aren't easy to find.  I'm not sufficiently familiar with this area to comment on how reasonable it would be for you to have found that question. Yes, you posted a comment in which you *added additional information* explaining why the existing answer didn't work for you, and in response, the answer was edited to correct for that.

Comment: I did not *add* any additional information, I merely pointed out that responder did not read my question at all. Why are you ignoring everything I write and repeat the same sentences all the time, when I pointed out three times why you are wrong? There was *no* way to find the answer because that answer *did not exist* at all at the time of asking! If there was an answer, there would have been no need to edit it all in the first place! Is it so difficult to understand?

Comment: @Mikhail Yes, you *did* add information.  You stated in a comment that you were under a constraint that you did not mention in the question.  That's adding information.  Actually it's changing the question, although in this case not inappropriately so in my opinion.  I'm not ignoring a sentence in your question in which you say that you can't change the function that you're calling because none is there.  But again, even if you added it to the question, it is now in the duplicate, so the question is still a duplicate.

Comment: The duplicate, at the time you asked your question, had an answer to the question you asked.  When you *changed your question* (in comments, you didn't actually change the *actual* question at all, even now) to add an additional constraint, the duplicate was also edited to address that constraint, keeping it a suitable duplicate.  If that wasn't done, as mentioned (and if you'd have edited your question accordingly), it'd have merited reopening.

Comment: Once again, I did not add any additional information. When you see a question about how to call a method from a nuget package, do you suggest to change the method signature? If yes, well, then I am helpless indeed. If no, then you should agree that I did not provide any information, and it is the responder who just wanted to abuse his rights.

Comment: @Mikhail If the library doesn't do what you want it to do, sure.  By all means, change it.  If you don't want to, or can't for some reason not apparent to any of the rest of us, then you can *say in the question that you can't change it*.  But we can't just assume that you can't change a function that, to the best of our knowledge, you most certainly can change.

Comment: not a single time when I asked a question about a library, I had to state that I am unable to change it. I checked some of your answers, and you do not suggest changing a signature of method when asked about some library, and authors do not mention at all that they cannot change the library. I heard a lot about hypocrisy on SO and how community is toxic, but refused to believe that till today. Guess I was wrong all that time. Thank you for your time, hope you enjoy abusing your mod privelege.

Comment: @Mikhail Me making a statement that I haven't made in the few of my posts that you've looked at isn't hypocrisy.  Hypocrisy is saying something that contradicts something else, not saying something that you just haven't said before (let alone something that you didn't say in every single statement you've ever made).  But anyways, apparently you have a problem with getting a fast and high quality answer to your question, and you consider it unacceptable that someone didn't repeat information posted in another post just for you instead of linking you to the existing post.  That baffles me.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest looking at this situation in a different way?

The net result here was that, eight minutes after having posted your question, you got a well-written answer to it, which is now available for everyone else through the target question. I'd say that's a good ending!

Perhaps you are bothered or offended by having your question closed as a duplicate. Please don't. [There is no shame in occasionally posting duplicate questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265736/2751851): non-obvious duplicates serve as signposts for searchers. In fact, if you really think the fact that you mention the WS-RS library might make it easier to find the answer, I encourage you to undelete your question -- it will be useful for that purpose even if it is closed.

As for your other concerns:

- On the behaviour of the answerer: I don't see anything underhanded. He closed your question in ~5 minutes, and added the extra section about three minutes after that. The edit happened only 50 seconds after your "not a duplicate" comment (which, by the way, was promptly replied to pointing out the added content, in case you had seen that question before the edit), so we can't even be cynical and say the answerer was trying to cover the tracks of the duplicate closure.
- On whether your question is a duplicate: while you do have an extra restriction to deal with ("I am using a library, hence it is not in my control of what types of parameters library accepts"), the target question doesn't explicitly rule out this scenario (i.e. in spite of the minimal example there, it doesn't explicitly state "assume I can change the interface at will"). That being so, and considering we are talking about a minor variation on the same theme, editing the target answer to make it more general is perfectly okay. At the end of the day, the test for a duplicate is: can a single answer reasonably cover both questions? And that is precisely what we see here.
- On appending the answer to your question to a long post: I'd say the answer is not long enough for that to be a problem. Note, though, that Shepmaster did try to address your concerns on this matter with [a further edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38677845/3), that brought the new section closer to the beginning.