# Is it acceptable to edit an old answer to cover a new question and then mark that new question as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Having one's question marked as a duplicate sends the message: "You didn't do your research correctly". This could discourage new users from asking questions, since it's one has to manually go look at that old questions's answer's edit history to see, that the edit that covers the new question was made after the new question. In a lot of forums it was very customary to add an insult to the closing of a duplicate question, to the point where, at least for me, the closing it self is an insult. I think it needs to be very obious to the question-asker, that the answer to their question was posted somewhere alse **after** they had asked the question.

Maybe something like a question-merge feature would be nice, or a way to link the old answer to the new question.

Comment: You could add a new answer to the old question instead of editing the old answer. This should solve the ethical question :)

Comment: Not at all. Duplicate sends the message 'your answer is here'. It's a way to help consolidate all the best answers in one place. If that answer was already answering that question and needed just a quick tweak to be on point, what is the value in not duplicating, and answering again instead?

Comment: Is it normal to get down voted this heavily on meta?

Comment: Votes on meta don't influence rep, so they are given a bit faster than on the main site. They also are used to indicate a difference of opinion here. So a lot of users likely think you don't see dupes the right way and downvote because of that.

Comment: "In a lot of forums it was very customary to add an insult to the closing of a duplicate question, to the point where, at least for me, the closing it self is an insult" -- Stack Overflow is not one of those forums, so you shouldn't see it as an insult. Posting a duplicate isn't always a bad thing: sometimes the duplicate target is not obvious or easy to find; and sometimes the duplicate question can be useful even if closed, by providing alternative search terms leading to the target question.

Comment: @duplode Ironic . Here's why this question is not a duplicate: The answers on the question you marked only talk about the specific post the user made and discredit his claims. My questions is about instances where this situation actually happens and how to handle it better.

Comment: It is pretty hard to guess what you're talking about.  That solution was proposed in a comment on Feb 24 '14 and adopted by the OP in an answer on Jan 15 '17.  It was never edited.  Even if it were, not spreading solutions across multiple pages and leaving future programmers to go hunt for them by themselves was a primary reason SO got started.

Comment: @Philippe The main message of my answer to that question is "please don't take it as an insult", which, I believe, applies just as well here.

Comment: @duplode Ok, maybe you should have looked for an actual duplicate

Comment: @Philippe In Stack Overflow, Y being a duplicate of X here means that the answers to X also cover Y, even if X and Y happen to be formulated in different ways. I believe that is the case here.

Comment: To duplode's point, I think his answer (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363428/close-question-as-dupe-and-edit-in-answer-in-target-to-better-handle-the-allege/363453#363453) could be c&ped here almost verbatim and still apply very well..

Answer (score 3):

If answer to an old question can be edited to cover new question don't that seems like a case where original answer must have some hint to the solution. And thus the question must be similar (if not identical).

Also as **Patrice** pointed-out in his comment, "Duplicate sends the message 'your answer is here'. It's a way to help consolidate all the best answers in one place." Which clarify that you perception of duplicate need a change. Take the SO's moderation sportingly and enjoy the knowledge that is shared.