# Mechanism to delete old duplicates? Flags?

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete

1. Is there an aim to remove identical old questions? (aka delete)
2. Is there any appropriate action? Flagging?

I keep finding old identical questions which are already be linked, end up looking at both, and get annoyed it hasn't been cleared up. Perhaps I have incorrect expectations about duplicate questions? Due to age and accumulated rep? They are closed, I just don't want to see it at all.

---

Case in point: c# string enums

same question, both have two useful answers: sealed class/use of the description property

[Associating enums with strings in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp)

[c#:How to use enum for storing string constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851567/chow-to-use-enum-for-storing-string-constants)

---

This didn't help me https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts
Meta Questions similar to mine that I found were unanswered. If my initial premise - being annoyed at finding multiples is flawed can someone point me at some site guidance so I can just drop it. Asking this so I don't potentially misuse flag mechanism.

Comment: Well the question is fundamentally different -  they are not my questions, and they are both really old. The answer is generic enough to suffice https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/1452172 I guess my problem is that the dupe question also has answers so I ended up reading both - and I keep coming across dupes with answers. Thanks :)

Comment: The problem is... the system is designed to not delete anything that *might* be useful. A duplicate question *might* be useful. If we want it deleted, enough people have to [vote to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) it, which is locked behind a privilage at 10k.

Comment: I'm confused what the problem is. Are you saying the two questions mentioned are duplicates but are not marked as such? You have enough rep to vote to close them as duplicates. If you don't want to read both... don't read both? As far as dupes having answers, that's because we're not fast enough in closing duplicates. It was only quite recently that the number of votes required to close a question was reduced to 3 from 5. That helps, but there's always people who don't want to see their special unique question closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @KevinB just 6000 more to go :'(. On a serious note I feel highly trained to be in the "suggested edit" review queue but not the close/reopen ones so I have disconnected from review queues entirely, I'm not likely to use any unlocked abilities if more come.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I see Qs closed as dupe almost immediately. IMO meta is ppl raging about removing dupes, protecting SEO, glorifying old good questions. Dupe questions AND answers is seemingly against prevailing opinion. So my expectations of the site wasn't met, dupe answers posted on the same page would downvoted to oblivion but on separate pages, I end up reading both. I didn't know that dupes were seen as useful to help an end user hit a Q to match their wording, then follow the dupe link to the great original with all the answers. Expectations altered, ex. given still doesn't fit the ideal

Comment: @ono2012 - don't forget that you are not "a user" of SO, you are moderator/content author... Most people who use SO don't even have an account - and for those people duplicate will never show up (due to instant redirect). It is useful to let people who can review question to see both original and duplicate as they may figure out that those are not duplicates or need any other moderation action (like you suggested flagging). If you don't want to see moderation part use non-signed in browser session...