# Question was made a duplicate for reasons that do no longer exist. Can the duplicate be withdrawn?

Tags: support, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

At the time of marking it as a duplicate, the other question had an answer that indirectly answered this question as well. That was already not a clear duplicate, though. And then, the accepted answer of the other question changed in such a way that the "answer" (taken as the accepted answer) was not even indirectly a duplicate anymore.

I do not see any option to vote for a re-opening of the question, I can just delete it instead.

[image]

And that would not be good since there is an answer of another user in the thread, and also, it makes no sense to me to delete a question just to post it again.

[Why does `conda list cudnn` have no output after `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` installation [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179991/why-does-conda-list-cudnn-have-no-output-after-conda-install-pytorch-torchvis)

I also might just ask the same question on Super User instead, where it rather belongs anyway, and delete it on Stack Overflow. Then again, I would rather migrate it than just delete it.

Deleting is not a good choice anyway, see [Should I delete my question if it is marked as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate).

If a question was made a duplicate for shallow reasons and for an answer that is no longer the accepted answer, how can such a duplicate be withdrawn?

Comment: There should be a reopen link. See [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415/289905). Have you edited the question to clarify that the duplicate target does not apply?

Comment: @SebastianSimon it is different from the duplicate target, no need to edit anything. The answer that I want to post is in the comment under the question, which shows that it is not a duplicate of the other accepted answer.

Comment: _“it is different from the duplicate target, no need to edit anything”_ — If you disagree with closure as duplicate, the proper response is to [edit] your post and explain exactly what is different and why. Asserting that it just _is_ different is not enough. See [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476/289905), ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon I have marked it as a duplicate myself, and the other question is my own question, so to whom shall I explain that it is not a duplicate?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I just see a terrible mistake of mine. I have *not* seen that the reopen link is *below* the question, and not in the box above. Sorry to take your time here!

Comment: Just a note, the status of an accepted answer doesn't really affect if the question is or is not a duplicate though.

Comment: @AndrewT. That is a point that depends on a clear duplicate in the other answers. And the other answer which inherits the idea is not a clear duplicate. I would not even mark it as a duplicate when that answer was still accepted. That other answer only indirectly explains it, and if you read it without explanation, you do not even see the point, at least as a beginner.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Your duplicate flag is not valid here, since that thread only explains how flagged as a duplicate works at all. In my case, I have flagged it myself, and the question here was just stupid since I had not searched the "reopen" link below the question. And that is not the content of [“This question already has answers here” - but it does not. What can I do when I think my question's not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-already-has-answers-here-but-it-does-not-what-can-i-do-when-i), else you would not see so many votes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just see my mistake. I have *not* seen that the "reopen" link is *below* the question, and not in the box above. Sorry to take your time here!

[image]